# Electric Potential at Points within a Circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

Consider the following circuit consisting of 2 batteries and 2 resistors.

[image]

How would I find the value of the potential at points $a$ and $b$?

In my initial attempt I assumed that the value of the current was consistent throughout the loop (which is where I think I went wrong) and tried to use Kirchoff's Loop Rule, giving, but seeing as there are no nodes I'm not sure how to go about solving it after.

*Additional Info Edit:* Using Kirchoff's, I thus far found:

V1 - R1*I - V2 - R2*I = 0

Solving for current:

I = (V1 - V2) / (R1 + R2)

And so the potential difference across is R1 is V = R1*I = R1*(V1 - V2) / (R1 + R2).

So the potential at *a* would be V1 - R1*(V1 - V2) / (R1 + R2).

Comment: The current is constant through the loop, so that was fine. Why don't you show us your work so far?

Comment: @Chris I added what I did so far (that didn't result in the correct result). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments: first off, $I$ is called "current," not "intensity." More importantly, you say the "potential difference across is V," but you don't clarify across *what*. And you seem to have solved for in the end the potential difference between b and a rather than the potential at a.

As a starting point, think about what it means to measure "the potential at a." Only potential differences have a physical meaning- so when we refer to "the potential at a," we really have to mean "the potential at a, *relative to some point we define as having zero potential*." What is the point defined to have a potential of 0? Once you figure that out, you should be able to find the potentials you're looking for.